# Java multi-threading slows down over long process, maximum CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing a program in java with Eclipse that analyzes large physical data sets and runs an iterative optimization process. While testing on a particularly large data set with many iterations, I'm seeing a phenomena that I can't explain.

Here's how the threads are set up:

```
List<String> scenarios;    
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
final int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1;

for(final String scenario: scenarios) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                innerLoopParallel(); //each optimization iteration
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        if(threads.size() < cores) {
            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
        }
    }
    for (Thread thread: threads) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My machine has 8 cores and I'm multi-threading onto 7 of the cores. The iterative process runs really fast at first and then slows considerably after running for about 20 minutes. My first thought was memory limitations, but I've been keeping an eye on the heap status (in Eclipse, Window -> preferences -> general -> "show heap status"), and it doesn't seem to be maxing out. However, my CPU has been maxed out (see image), with fans blowing hard. At every iteration it is supposed to print a line to the console, but it started writing in chunks as the program slowed, printing 20 at a time.

[image: Max CPU Usage]

I know this question is somewhat vague, but I'm running out of ideas. Do you have any suggestions to point me in the right direction? Could the multi-threading be causing an issue? Is it possible that a for-loop might build up CPU somehow by not closing some process? Feel free to ask questions if you need clarifications on anything.

Comment: Unless you share any of the code you're using, possible answers will be pretty much guesses / hand-waving.

Comment: Maybe the CPU is overheating. If the fans are blowing hard, you should check the CPU temperature and check if the CPU is throttling. It can be a hardware issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Is it possible that a for-loop might build up CPU somehow by not closing some process? "* - what "process" are you talking about?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I added some code to show the threading. The function being run gets a lot more complicated and would be difficult to add.

Comment: @StephenC No particular process in mind. I'm simply at a loss for why the code is slowing and am grasping at straws. Sounds like that's not a thing.

Comment: Are these 8 real cores or 4 cores and 4 virtual (Hyperthreading like) cores? Hyperthreading cores share internal processing components with the real core. This can result in less performance (no linear scaling). Some CPU models can boost the clock if not all cores are loaded. The clock can go down if all cores are loaded to match the power usage limits. These may be system depending options why it's slower with lot cores. Other may be CPU cache data eviction by different threads.

Comment: @Konrad You are correct, there are 4 cores, 8 with hyperthreading, so that probably factors into the baseline speed. But with how this slowness ramps up over time, your comment on cache data eviction is one I'll follow up on.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Use a profiler to figure out where your application is spending all of its time.

> Could the multi-threading be causing an issue?

Potentially.  Especially if you create too many threads and / or are doing too much context switching between threads.

> Is it possible that a for-loop might build up CPU somehow by not closing some process?

That question doesn't really make sense (to me).

But it is plausible for loops take longer and longer because they are operating on larger and larger data structures.  And there many other possible reasons why an algorithm may get very slow / very CPU intensive over time.

Advice:

- Analyze your code / algorithms and the way you are *using* threads.
- Consider doing a Big O complexity analysis.
- Consider whether your application is causing excessive memory contention and cache thrashing due to non-localised memory access patterns.

**UPDATE**

I can see problems with your thread code.  For example, it looks like some threads will never be started. But there are also clear signs<sup>1</sup> that this is not *real* code, so analyzing it is of doubtful utility.

But instead of doing it like that, I think you should either use an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread pool, of a fork join pool.  (Not sure which would be best .... because your example code is too abstracted.)  Doing your own thread pool management is not a good idea, and hasn't been for 20-something years!

On the other hand, there is no real evidence one way or the other that threading is the problem.  See my *earlier* advice!

---

<sup>1 -  For example, the monitoring shows that there are >2500 native threads.  But that shouldn't happen with the code you have shown us.</sup>